Swagger why is #/components/schemas/ missing for some of my $ref?
I'm generating an OpenAPI spec using org.springdoc:openapi-gradle-plugin:1.9.0 and org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.8.0 in a project using Boot 2.
All of the referenced schemas are defined at the bottom of the spec, but some of the references are made without the #/components/schemas/ prefix: I get for instance "$ref": "pf.Machin" instead of the expected "$ref": "#/components/schemas/pf.Machin".
I couldn't spot any Swagger annotation specific to the faulty types.
Any clue why this #/components/schemas/ prefix is omitted sometimes?
Edit:
I found a common point between the classes generated without #/components/schemas/: all are decorated with @JsonIdentityInfo(property = "uuid", generator = ObjectIdGenerators.UUIDGenerator.class)
Still, I don't understand why this has an impact on the generated OpenAPI spec, and worse, I don't know how to have the $ref correctly generated (so that the spec is valid and client code can be generated) :/
